# Sufficent condition that a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I was wondering if it is sufficient for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ to be continuous that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} f(h, 0) = \lim_{k\to 0} f(0, k)$$
As far as I knew this was the case, yet the function $f(x, y) = \frac{2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ suffices this condition since both limits are $0$, but $\lim_{m \to \infty}f(\frac{1}{m}, \frac{1}{m}) = \frac{1}{2} \neq 0$, so the function can't be continuous. Maybe someone can help me figure out where I'm wrong...
Thanks!

Comment: See, looking at the "open set" definition of continuity, any sufficient condition at a point has got to constrain the values of $f$ on *every open set* around a point, to be close to the function value at that point. The reason why your logic doesn't work, and the given statement is false, is that the condition (when thought of as implying continuity at the point $0$) doesn't constrain at all, the values of any open set around $0$, but rather only the axes values. Thus, any other values are free to do what they want i.e. be far away from $f(0)$.

Comment: If you want a sufficient condition , along with the given condition, for continuity, then you will have to consider the notion of a partial derivative (bounded) : this will, when combined with a mean-value inequality, constrain all the values in a neighbourhood of $0$ since although not every point in a neighbourhood of $0$ lies on the axes, it doesn't lie too far away, and we can use MVE to constrain its function value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided a counter-example yourself. Here is a simpler one:$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if $x=0$ or $y=0$}\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$It is clearly discontinuous at $(0,0)$, right?! However, you always have $f(h,0)=f(0,k)=0$. In particular,$$\lim_{h\to0}f(h,0)=\lim_{k\to0}f(0,k)=0.\tag1$$

The equalities $(1)$ only tell you something about what happens to $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis, but nothing about when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ in general.

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering the whole time since it seemed that this condition is not enough! So to check continuity I would have to prove for every single sequence that the limit of the function values is the function value of the limit of the sequence.

Comment: Yes, for every single sequence converging to $(0,0)$.

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure it works this way then: If we define a function $(x, y)$ converging to $(0,0)$, we can say that $(x, y) = (x, ax)$, with $a \in \mathbb{R}$. So now we have reduced the convergence in two variables to a convergence in $x$, and if this function $f(x, ax)$ converges to $0$ as $x \to 0$, then it is continuous in $(0,0)$.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Like that, you only see what happens when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along a straight line (and you are missing the line $x=0$). If$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}&\text{ if }(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$then all those limits that you have mentioned are equal to $0$, but $f$ is still discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: But can I check $(x, ax)$, $(x, 0)$, $(0, y)$ to be safe?

Comment: Yes. If you get different limits, then $f$ will be discontinuous at $(0,0)$. Otherwise, you don't know whether it is continuous or not.